# How can I access the value and position of entry in array in python with one statement?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I'm using a for loop to run through all the values stored in a 2-d numpy array. Python beautifully lets me do this very simply, without having to loop through the column/rows with two loops with:

```
for cell in CM:
    if cell == 1: do something
```

but now I want another statement that allows me to modify the concordant position in a different 2-d numpy array. I could easily get around this by:

```
for row in CM:
    for column in CM:
        if CM[column][row] == 1: do something
        othermatrix[column][row] = 5
```

but I'd like to do it in a more pythonic way and utilize the single for statement.

I realize, after the comment from Jonathan Eunice below, that the array I going through with the first for loop in my question was not 2-d at all (I had flattened it so I COULD use the simple loop).  But, the answer below from AChampion is what I was after, so I'll leave the question.

Comment: I'm confused by your claim that your first `for` loop iterates over all of the cells in a 2d `CM`. It seems to iterate over just the rows, which would be type `numpy.ndarray`, and thus never `== 1`.  [AChampion's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34847298/240490) would be the appropriate way to iterate over individual cells/values.

Comment: Actually, you are right Jonathan Eunice: I had flattened the array earlier (and forgotten I had done so), so I was running through a 1-d, my mistake. However, I can now use the answer below to run through my non-flattened array, which is more convenient and still the answer I was after- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `np.ndenumerate()`, which operates like the standard python `enumerate` but returns the index, e.g. a tuple `(row, col)`:

```
for (row, col), cell in np.ndenumerate(CM):
    if cell == 1: do something
    othermatrix[row][col] = 5
```

Comment: It's best not to use chained indexing (i.e. use `othermatrix[row, col]` rather than `othermatrix[row][col]`)